# how can i create multiple view on a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

i have 2 classes with

1. class view1.(from create project with view-base application the gray in background)
2. class view2.(from add file uiviewcontroller subclass for view1,view2,view3 and view4)

in class view1 i create 4 uiview variable v1,v2,v3,v4 and link it to view 1,view 2, view 3 and view 4

in viewdidload of view1

i code

```
view2 *sub =[[view2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"view2" bundle:nil];
self.v1 = sub.view; (v1,v2,v3,v4 is view that i draw by interface builder on self.view)
```

but when run view2 that i create did not appear;

how can i make it appear.

view1  http://postimage.org/image/2mqhcxb1g/

view2  http://postimage.org/image/2mqj0gnj8/

thank you

Comment: so u want it as view1 picture??

Comment: dont forget to accept one of the anwsers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will appear in viewDidLoad: (for view2 only)

```
View2 *view2 = [[View2 alloc]
initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];

[self.view insertSubview:view2.view atIndex:0];
[view2 release];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Try to give frame for this to set at desire position. And follow same for other 3 views...

**EDIT**

```
- (void)loadView
{
// Create the main view
CGRect appRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:appRect];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// Provide support for autorotation and resizing
contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
self.view = contentView;
[contentView release];

// reset the origin point for subviews. The new origin is 0,0
appRect.origin = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
// Add the subviews, each stepped by 32 pixels on each side
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(appRect, 32.0f, 32.0f)];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[contentView addSubview:subview];
[subview release];

subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(appRect, 64.0f, 64.0f)];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
[contentView addSubview:subview];
[subview release];

subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(appRect, 96.0f, 96.0f)];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[contentView addSubview:subview];
[subview release];

}
```

Comment: in self.view have 4 views on top of it i would like to show view2 on 4 views not in self.view

Answer (score 2):

right now you just assign that view to a variable, to make a view visible you should do the following:

```
[self.view addSubView:sub];
```

This will add the view to your current view and make it visible.

Comment: thank you every one i found [code] v1 addSubView:sub.view; is useful.